Are cockroaches attracted to the dust particles is that a primary reason that I have cockroaches in my kitchen? Would like to know more about yhat
Same as title, are cockroaches attracted to the dust particles is that a primary reason that I have cockroaches in my kitchen?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
